# Error while declaring int variable using curly braces in g++

Tags: c++

I compiled this code using g++ and got an error:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int j{ 0 };
    cout << "j = " << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    int j{ 0 };
         ^
         ;
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Which compiler(which version)?

Comment: What version of C++ are you building as (the `-std=` option to g++)?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably used an old version of compiler .

On [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/TibaFX), I have checked that it may be older than 4.4.7.

You may have to add `-std=c++11` flag to compile.

Newer compiler has this standard enable as default.